# [RestKit v0.20.3]: Logging to file

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20, libcomponentlogging

I want `RestKit` to log its errors and warning messages to a file.

It correctly logs those messages with `NSLog`, but nothing more; although I added the following two pods to my project:

```
pod 'LibComponentLogging-pods'
pod 'LibComponentLogging-LogFile'
```

I managed to log normal logs to a file:

```
lcl_log(lcl_cMain, lcl_vInfo, @"log message %d", 2);
```

This log for example is shown in the created log file, but not the RestKit logs.

How can I tell RestKit to redirect its logs to the same file, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at example 2 at https://github.com/aharren/LibComponentLogging-configure

After a `pod install`, you can run `lcl_configure pod` which will integrate the RestKit pod with your LibComponentLogging pods.
RestKit will then use the logging back-end which is configured via your Podfile.

`lcl_configure` will be installed via the `LibComponentLogging-pods` pod and can be called via `Pods/LibComponentLogging-pods/configure/lcl_configure pod`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but an immediate and slightly 'hacky' option could be to override `NSLog` with `lcl_log()`.

```
#define NSLog(x) lcl_log(lcl_cMain, lcl_vInfo, x, 2);
```